# Adjust the bounding box dimensions of object manualy without affecting size of the mesh

Tags: mesh, dimensions

I got a equilateral triangle (all measuring the same length) with the (bounding box) size of 10,10,8.66. I need it to stay this size since I am using it in a Lua script. The problem is, i want the triangle beveled. If I do this, the size changes due to the cut edges - to something like 9.8,10,84 … This messes up my lua scripts alignment and snapping mechanism.

Do I have any options to have the triangle beveled and yet keep the original size? resizing/scaling after beveling is not an option as this would cause alignment issues. Creating junk geometry - Verticies without faces does not either seem to work, as the 3d engine i am using automaticaly adds faces to verticies without.

Any ideas? There must be some way of manipulating the bounding box size manualy?

[image]

Comment: No, you cannot manipulate the bounding box manually independent from the mesh, because it is not an individual object, but an information derived from the mesh. The only thing you could do in _Geometry Nodes_ is get the bounding box data from the mesh before beveling and store these informations in attributes. But first this means you would have to use _Geometry Nodes_ (and I don't know if this is desired since you provide no info how you use the bounding box data) and it's also unfortunate that there is no bevel option inside _Geometry Nodes_, though that might not be too bad.

Comment: I havent used geometry nodes before. But by storing it in attributes, what will that do? I export the object as an fbx and import it into roblox where i have a lua script that uses the dimensions of the object to align and place stuff

Comment: Storing it in attributes does nothing, it is just the bounding box values stored are there in the attributes even after the bounding box got changed. But this is one of the reasons why it's always good to tell what you need it for, because not everybody (including me) automatically understands what "lua script" is. _Geometry Nodes_ are Blender specific and I mentioned them supposing you need the data in Blender - they are not supported by the FBX file format, so this will not work. I have no idea if you can transfer the attributes to any properties that are supported by the FBX export format.

Comment: ...and not to misunderstand anything - I guess in lua script there is no readout of a "predefined" bounding box dimension either, it is just calculated in realtime from the current mesh?

Comment: What I might have to do is to predefine the bounding box dimensions in my Lua script instead of getting it from the mesh, and then do some calculations to offset the pivot/anchor point of the model.